# regex URL not working because of missing escape character

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm building a function that looks like this:

```
function CheckIfValidURL(TheURL) {

    return /@(https?|ftp)://(-\.)?([^\s/?\.#-]+\.?)+(/[^\s]*)?$@iS/.test(TheURL);
}
```

Basically, it should return true or false if the URL passes the regex, which BTW I got from http://mathiasbynens.be/demo/url-regex The problem is that the `/` character is also part of the URL so it's not escaping it. What do I need to do to fix this and use `.test()`

Comment: Show us URL's that should be validated and one that shouldn't

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape forward slashes using `\/`.
Otherwise, they will be parsed as the end of the regex literal.